# BBLayers.conf specify path using environment variable

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to configure a Yocto build and would like to be able to specify the path to a layer in `bblayers.conf` via an environment variable. This will allow engineers to checkout a configuration and build without needing to manually modify `bblayers.conf` so to specify the absolute path to their checkout of the kernel module.

I have tried exporting a variable in my `.zshrc` file, e.g.

```
export TRIALS=~/TRIALS
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt to access it in `bblayers.conf` the value is not set:

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""
TRIALS_DIR = "${@os.environ['TRIALS']}"

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-amd/meta-amd-bsp \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-amd/meta-amd-distro \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-congatec-amd \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-dpdk \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  ${TRIALS_DIR}/hello-layer \
  "
```

The error I get is

```
bb.BBHandledException
ERROR: Failure expanding variable TRIALS_DIR, expression was 
    ${@os.environ['TRIALS']} which triggered exception KeyError: 'TRIALS'
```

How do I set an environment variable in my shell that can be accessed from `belayers.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bitbake** tightly controls the build environment to prevent unwanted contamination. This can be overridden by including any variables that you need to access to the `BB_ENV_WHITELIST`.

For my example above I added the `$TRIALS` variable to `BB_ENV_WHITELIST` via

```
export BB_ENV_WHITELIST="$BB_ENV_WHITELIST TRIALS"
```

After setting `BB_ENV_WHITELIST` it was necessary to re-initialise `bitbake` via:

```
cd ~/poky
source oe-init-build-env
```

The `$TRIALS` environment variable could then be accessed directly in `bblayers.conf`:

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-amd/meta-amd-bsp \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-amd/meta-amd-distro \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-congatec-amd \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-dpdk \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  /home/ahk/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  ${TRIALS}/hello-layer \
  "
```